# How to get the shadow render pass cycles?

Tags: rendering

How to get the shadow render pass cycles? I know that this pass was removed and instead Blender has a shadow catcher. Its logic is that an object that is not needed in the render is excluded from the rendering. But I have a large scene with dozens of objects and I don't need to exclude anything from the render by looping through a large list of objects. I need a shadow pass that I can then combine with occlusion in compositing to get a nice solid shadow. Now when I watch the shadow catcher pass I get a white screen.
I can't find a solution that meets my specific needs. On YouTube, there are mainly solutions for excluding objects that do not participate in the rendering.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for several days. I was offered an interesting option for using the override material. In one move, without ruining the scene, he repaints everything in the scene as if it were made of white plaster, the whole thing looks quite similar to a shadow pass. And just with one click it is removed from the scene, returning it to the original materials. Of course this will be an additional render pass. But it seems that this was the case before in production for the production of masks and occlusion. In case someone finds it useful 8)